# Form a large matrix from n numbers of small matrices

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, append, concatenation

I am a new to MATLAB. I have generated `n` smaller matrices of numbers, say `3 x 1` by using a `FOR` loop.  All the matrices are having random values like so:

```
m1 = [3;2;1];   
m2 = [5;1;6];
m3 = [0.2;0.8;7]
m4 = [8;3;0] 
m5 = [3;7;6]
m6 = [8;2;1.3].
```

Now I want to concatenate all the values into a larger matrix `M` such that `M` can be represented like this:

```
M = [m1 m2 m3; m4 m5 m6]
```

So that the output of `M` shall be:

```
M = [3 5 0.2;
     2 1 0.8;
     1 6 7;
     8 3 8; 
     3 7 2;
     0 6 1.3];
```

How do I initialize that by using a `FOR` loop or anything else so that every time the increase of the counter value i.e `i`, this will result in an insertion of a new matrix (`m1`,`m2` & so on) inside the bigger matrix i.e `M`?

Note that `M` is a very large matrix (maybe around 40 x 40) and so I am having a lot of smaller matrices.

Comment: this  is my own problem , i am developing a project in decision making tools using MATLAB. i have not copied it from somewhere existing examples. The datas provided  are for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Do your really need the individual variables? Probably such a solution is simpler, using only one mmatrix:

```
M=zeros(40,40)
for idx=1:size(M,1)
   M(idx,:)=your_code_here()
end
```

Whenever you would have used `M1` before, now use `M(1,:)` to get the first row of `M`

Comment: off course,I need the individual values along with their Matrices. I need to display each of the smaller matrices.  m1 , m2 , m3 are obtained from the for loop only . i have the generalised syntax ie mi for each small matrix. Moreover , if i will follow your solution [m1,m2,m2,m3,m4;......... (upto how much i will write)] , since the M matrix is a bigger one

Comment: Thank yoy Daniel .Off course,I need the individual values along with their Matrices. First of all I need to display each of the smaller matrices.  m1 , m2 , m3  those are obtained from the 1st FOR  loop only . i have the generalised syntax ie mi for each small matrix. any further Tips ?

Comment: You can display each slice individually using ˋdisp(M(idx,:))ˋ, please explain why this solution does not work for you. Using variable names like m1, m2, m3 is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @ Daniel;  respected Sir , Kindly follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473410/inserteing-the-elements-from-several-matrices-to-form-a-large-matrix-in-matlab

Comment: @pradeepkumarTarei: Your new question does not explain your problems with this answer. No idea how I could help...

Comment: @ Daniel , Respected Sir , My question may be new but the difficulty remains same . I have edited the new question for better explanation . Kindly help me the same .here it goes.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473410/inserteing-the-elements-from-several-matrices-to-form-a-large-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 0):

This seems as highly inefficient way to put matrices together, but every MatLab newbie should pass through this stage in his evolution.
If you use for loop, you should create your matrices in such a way that they can be indexed using your loop variable, otherwise there is no point to use the loop. Try cell arrays, for example:

```
m{1}=[3;2;1];
m{2}=[5;1;6];
m{3}=[.2;.8;7];
m{4}=[8;3;0];
m{5}=[3;7;6];
m{6}=[8;2;1.3];
```

Now you can merge them in a for loop:

```
M = [];
NBlocks = length(m) / 3;
for b=1:NBlocks
    M = [M; [m{(b-1)*3+1} m{(b-1)*3+2} m{(b-1)*3+3}] ];
end
```

*NOTE* This code is highly inefficient, especially for big matrices, and provided only for educational purposes. Consider redesigning your task to use matrix preallocation for your `M` matrix.

Comment: @ anandr , Sir please try to sort out this .my code is as follows.  ts=input('PLEASE INPUT THE TOTAL NUMBERS OF SUBCRITERIAS \n');
 for i=1:1:ts
    M=zeros(5,5);
 %for idx=1:size(M,1)
   % M(idx,:)=your_code_here()
 %end
 fprintf('PLEASE ENTER NO % d DECISION MATRIX WITH PROPER DIMENSION',i);
    mi=input(''); 
    disp(mi);
    NBlocks = length(m) / 3;
for b=1:NBlocks
    M = [M; [mi{(b-1)*3+1} mi{(b-1)*3+2} mi{(b-1)*3+3}] ];
end
 end    
AND IT SHOWS 
??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object.

Error in ==> Try2 at 12
    M = [M; [mi{(b-1)*3+1} mi{(b-1)*3+2} mi{(b-1)*3+3}] ];

Comment: @pradeepkumarTarei Please do not add code in comments; it is impossible to read. Instead, edit your question and add it there being sure to indent an additional 4 spaces on each line to get code formatting.

Comment: @ anandr , Please follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473410/inserteing-the-elements-from-several-matrices-to-form-a-large-matrix-in-matlab