# Inserteing the elements from several matrices to form a Large matrix in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, for-loop, matrix

I am a new to MATLAB. I have generated n  numbers of smaller matrices of (3 x 1 ) by using a FOR loop. All the matrices are having random values .Now I want to concatenate all the values to form a LARGE matrix 'M'
Please check out my codes below .

```
n= input('please input the number of criterias \n');
for k=1:1:n
    fprintf('Please input the %d X %d  decision matrix for no %d Criteria \n', n,n,k);
    m=input('');
    S=sum(m);
for i=1:1:n
    for j=1:1:n
    m(i,j)= m(i,j)/S(j);
    end
end
rS=sum(m,2);
 pk=rS/n;
 fprintf('the prioritized  matrix for no %d criteria ) is ::\n',k);
 disp(pk);
 end`
```

### and the Command window shows the O/p like this

```
please input the number of criterias 
3
Please input the 3 X 3  decision matrix for no 1 Criteria 
[1 2 3 ; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
the prioritized  matrix for no 1 criteria ) is ::
    0.1278
    0.3333
    0.5389

Please input the 3 X 3  decision matrix for no 2 Criteria 
[4 5 6; 3 7 9; 8 1 4]
the prioritized  matrix for no 2 criteria ) is ::
    0.3224
    0.4040
    0.2736

Please input the 3 X 3  decision matrix for no 3 Criteria 
[1 5 4 ; 2 7 0; 3 6 7]
the prioritized  matrix for no 3 criteria ) is ::
    0.2694
    0.2407
    0.4899
```

### Now  I want to append the values obtained from all the smaller resultant matrices (prioritized matrices) in order to form a LARGE MATRIX 'M'. 'M'  shall look like this

```
M = [ .1278 .3224 .2644 ;
      .3333 .4040 .2407 ;
      .5839 .2736 .4899 ]
```

### Now Please guide me how could i do this in an efficient way ? 
 NOTE : 'M' is not always a 3X3 matrix , Its a huge order dimension (arround 40X40) in my real project and moreover Its not always fixed and It depends upon the USER INPUT i.e 'n' . I am  extremely sorry for the previous Formatting mistakes.

Comment: You seem new to SO too.  Take a little time to understand how to format your questions for ease of reading.  See those little symbols above the edit box where you enter your text ?  There's one that looks a bit like **{ }**.  That's for formatting code.  Try it.  Have a look at other questions and get some appreciation of how they look.

Comment: Yeah just to second that, the loops are not really relevant to what you are asking, so instead of including them, just ask about matrix concatenation since that is what you are trying to understand. The rest of it just clutters your question.

Comment: @ Daniel , @ David Eisenstat , @ Jonas Schnelli , @ stefan P , @ Reto Koradi ; I am extremely sorry for the wrong presentation format. Kindly Recheck my question . I have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see what is going on with your loops, but this example should help. Matrix concatenation is done with commas (to add columns) or semi-colons (to add rows). So if you have three row matrices of size 1x3 that look like:

```
m1=[.1278 .3224 .2644]
m2=[.3338 .4040 .2407]
m3=[.5839 .2736 .4899]
```

you can make a 3x3 matrix M concatenating your small matrices with semi-colons:

```
M=[m1;m2;m3]
```

that looks like this:

```
M =

   0.12780   0.32240   0.26440
   0.33380   0.40400   0.24070
   0.58390   0.27360   0.48990
```

Comment: @ Will , I need the individual values along with their Matrices. I need to display each of the smaller matrices. m1 , m2 , m3 are obtained from the for loop only . i have the generalised syntax ie mi for each small matrix. Moreover , if i will follow your solution [m1,m2,m2,m3,m4;......... (upto how much i will write)] , since the M matrix is a bigger one and i will depend upon the user i/p .

Comment: It looks like you have asked a variant of this question three times and received numerous answers not to your liking. Maybe try clarifying your question, because a lot of people have tried helping. Don't make a new question, just edit one that you have already asked for clarity, because I can't tell what you're trying to do.